# Getting data from an xml file based on array from another query from another xml file

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have this xml file for table student and below is the structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <StudentModules>
  <Student Student_ID="001">
    <Module  ID="M001" />
    <Module  ID="M002" />
    <Module  ID="M003" />
    <Module  ID="M004" />
  </Student>

  <Student Student_ID="002">
    <Module ID="M005"/>
    <Module ID="M006" />
    <Module ID="M007"/>
    <Module ID="M008" />
  </Student>
```

Then I have this file for modules and below is the structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ModuleSchedule>
  <ModuleTimeTable Module_ID="M001" ModuleName="Module Name 1">
    <Slot Day="Monday" Time="09:30"/>
    <Slot Day="Tuesday" Time="14:30"/>
    <Slot Day="Fridayday" Time="09:30"/>
    <Slot Day="Saturday" Time="12:30"/>
  </ModuleTimeTable>
 <ModuleTimeTable Module_ID="M002" ModuleName="Module Name 2">
    <Slot Day="Monday" Time="09:30"/>
    <Slot Day="Tuesday" Time="14:30"/>
    <Slot Day="Fridayday" Time="09:30"/>
    <Slot Day="Saturday" Time="12:30"/>
 </ModuleTimeTable>
 <ModuleTimeTable Module_ID="M003" ModuleName="Module Name 3">
    <Slot Day="Monday" Time="09:30"/>
    <Slot Day="Tuesday" Time="14:30"/>
    <Slot Day="Fridayday" Time="09:30"/>
    <Slot Day="Saturday" Time="12:30"/>    
 </ModuleTimeTable>
```

I want to use the first xml file to get all modules (Module ID) where `Student_ID` is for example 001. And them I use the results for my second query which is supposed to get all module names where module ID is array result one.

Here is what I have,

```
// first linq query

 XDocument stdoc = XDocument.Load(@"E:\studentModules.xml");

     var StudM = (from item in stdoc.Descendants("Student")
                 where item.Attribute("Student_ID").Value.Equals("001")
                 select item);

     foreach (XElement n in StudM)
      {

          var result = (from node in n.Descendants()
                      select new
                      {
                          Mod_ID = node.Attribute("ID").Value
                      });



       }

//second query (doesnt do the job)
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"E:\Module_Schedule.xml");
 var items = from item in doc.Descendants("ModuleTimeTable")
                where item.Attribute("Module_ID").Value.Contains("result")// doesnt     work
                    select new
                  {
                      ModuleId = (string)item.Attribute("Module_ID").Value,
                      ModuleName = (string)item.Attribute("ModuleName").Value

                   };


        GridView1.DataSource = items.ToList();
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

How can I change this to work. I want to get module name and Ids from from `Module_Schedule.xml` which have the same ID as in the array IDs returned from the first xml-file.

//EDIT
At the moment it returns an empty gridview, No errors. I think the problem is with how I can call for the first variable var result in the second query

Comment: How is it not working for you now?

Comment: At the moment it returns an empty gridview, No errors. I think the problem is with how I can call for the frirst variable var result in the second query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in this code block:

```
foreach (XElement n in StudM)
{
    var result =
        from node in n.Descendants()
        select new { Mod_ID = node.Attribute("ID").Value };
}
```

You keep assigning to result, which is not only defined only within the `foreach` loop, not outside it, but you never save or do anything with the result variable. So it's both not available in the scope outside of the loop, and is also being overwritten after every iteration of the loop.

This should work:

```
var students = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\Keoki\Desktop\students.xml");
var modules = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\Keoki\Desktop\modules.xml");

var items =
    from s in students.Descendants("Student")
    where s.Attribute("Student_ID").Value == "001"
    select s.Descendants().Attributes("ID").Select(a => a.Value)
    into ids
    from m in modules.Descendants("ModuleTimeTable")
    where ids.Contains(m.Attribute("Module_ID").Value)
    select new {
       ModuleId = m.Attribute("Module_ID").Value,
       ModuleName = m.Attribute("ModuleName").Value
    };
```

Comment: It doesnt work either if I put the second query inside the loop. Can you pse suggest to me a better way of how I can change this.

Comment: would you be able to help me if at all you can with this one. "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22912493/gridview-with-a-dropdownlist-to-xml-file"